# Copy row based on multiple criteria(s)

Tags: vba, excel

My code only copies the first row that satisfies the two criteria that I set and then it stops, not sure where I got it wrong.

The code is intended to copy the row if the value "Active" is found under the column header "Status". The column headers are dynamic therefore I had to code it accordingly.

Here is the code :

```
   Sub copystatus()
        Dim LR as long
        Dim LC as integer
        Dim ws as worksheet
        Dim ws2 as worksheet



        Set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("Data")
        Set ws2 = thisworkbook.sheets("Target")

        LR = ws.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
       LC = ws.cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft).column

      With ws
          For x = 1 to LC
           If .cells(1,x).value = "Status" then
              For i = 2 to LR
                   If .cells(I,x).value = "Active" then
                Rows(i).copy destination:=ws2.range("A:L")
                   End if
              Next 
          End if
      Next
     End with

 End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this myself, here is the final version of the code, in case you need it. I learnt that the object rows also has a value property just like cells/range which can be altered in the same manner

```
   Sub copystatus()

       Dim LR as long
       Dim LC as integer
       Dim LR2 as Long
       Dim ws as worksheet
       Dim ws2 as worksheet



      Set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("Data")
      Set ws2 = thisworkbook.sheets("Target")

      LR = ws.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
      LC = ws.cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft).column

      With ws
         For x = 1 to LC
           If .cells(1,x).value = "Status" then
              For i = 2 to LR
                If .cells(I,x).value = "Active" then
                        LR2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                        ws2.Rows(LR2 + 1).Value = .Rows(x).Value
                End if
              Next 
          End if
         Next
     End with

  End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically change your copy Destination Range. It will always copy your result in the same cells and they will get overwritten.

Try something like this to copy in Row LR (no blank rows in target sheet) and column 1

```
LR2 = ws2.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(LR2, 1)
```

Comment: Silly me to have forgotten to copy that from my code. but, You don't know what you're talking about because that's not where the problem is

Comment: Maybe you can try to elaborate your problem a bit further or what your data structure looks like. That'll be very helpful. (:

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry, yeah it appears to only copy the first row with the header "Status" and the value "Active" (underneath the "Status" header")

Comment: Alright, that's pretty much what your code says. (; What kind of data is in the Status and Active columns? Which data do you want to copy under what circumstances?

Comment: edited my answer. if this doesnt fix it, describe the data structure of your table

Comment: Nope,  By doing that you're limiting the copy to a single column. This code is intended to copy the entire row if a value "Active" is found under the header "Status"

Comment: Nope (: This is just the target cell, it will still copy the whole row. Just added another piece so that you will have no blank rows in your target sheet.

Comment: That's not gonna work Tom, why would you do row count on the target worksheet?? that's certainly not going to work

Comment: Because you need to know where to copy the next entry. The code works for me, did you try it already? (This fragment obviously has to be included in the if then-part of your for loop.)